# Why does OutputStream.write() closes socket connection?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, sockets

I'm developing and android application that communicates with a server through sockets. I have one thread reading the socket, while the Main thread executes an `Asynk Task` that sends the messages through the same socket. The problem here is, there are some times (lets say 50% of times) that I call the  `OutputStream.write()` method of the socket connection, the servers log shows that the client closed connection. I read that the java sockets are full duplex, which should allow me to send and receive messages through the same socket with no problems. So, why is this happening? Is the problem from the application? Or is it the server side code (to which I dont have access) the one closing the connection??

EDIT: The server is a raspberry Pi with a raspbian distribution, running only one java application which is the one communicating with my application. I have no access to the java code running on the server, or any of the logs the server shows, I only can acces to the screen connected to the server, which prints the messages the code "tells" it to print. When I execute the OutputStram.Write(), the server shows on screen: "Connection to client closed".

Many Thanks!

Comment: What exception are you getting?  It should be in your Android logs.

Comment: I suspect that the server has closed the connection.

Comment: "The servers log shows that the client closed connection": no it doesn't. *Show* us what the log really contains.

Comment: I'm looking at what the server is showing on screen because I don't have access to the server code, or any of the logs the code shows.

Answer (score 3):

> Why does OutputStream.write() closes socket connection?

It doesn't. It writes data to an `OutputStream.`

> some times (lets say 50% of times) that I call the OutputStream.write() method of the socket connection, the servers log shows that the client closed connection.

No it doesn't. This is what it really shows:

> When I execute the OutputStram.Write(), the server shows on screen: "Connection to client closed".

This says that the *server* closed the connection *to* the *client.* Not the other way around.

Probably you sent something invalid and the server barfed.

Comment: What I am actually sending is a String that the server manipulates and saves on a database. Let me double check with the server admin.